# Can I 'emulate' a device by booting its BIOS on my PC?

Tags: emulation

So for example let's take a SEGA Genesis (Mega Drive).

Let's say I have a usb Genesis cartridge loader with Sonic 1 plugged in. In that case, could I 'hardware emulate' a Genesis by booting a Genesis BIOS from USB (or any other way to boot a Genesis BIOS) and use that to play or mod Sonic 1, or develop & test home-brew games for the console?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with game development.

Comment: I was gonna use this for development use. @Philipp

Comment: @TimoHerngreen Although your intentions are related to game development, the question itself can be better answered by generic CS/SE specialists and professionals rather than game developers in particular.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use an actual emulator? No need to mess with the hardware this way, and you can still develop and test video games.

Comment: I actually built a wrote my own Genesis development hardware from scratch, see https://nestenius.se/2022/01/18/how-i-built-my-own-sega-mega-drive-hardware-dev-kit-from-scratch/

Answer (score 2):

No, the BIOS is not sufficient to emulate console hardware for development purposes, or running software generally.

A BIOS is firmware designed to work with specific hardware. Your PC is not a console, and loading a BIOS image won't transform it into one. At best, the BIOS image will be completely meaningless to your PC, like handing an English-speaker a set of instructions written in Greek.

What you're looking for is an Emulator. This is software that runs on one device, and simulates the behaviour of a different device. You'd need this kind of simulation layer to even make sense of a BIOS image designed for a different device.